# Calculus 2 figure problem

Tags: calculus, area

Let S(ε) be the face of the figure bounded by y = e^x and y=x+1+є. We assume that ε is a small positive number. For ε -> 0 we have
S(ε) = So + ε ^ α . S₁ +..., a > 0.
Find S0, S1 and α.

(ε - epsilon)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Unfortunately, your post doesn’t fully meet this site’s policy (see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)). I recommend that you edit your post. (1) Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to type all your formulae. (2) You should provide some context to your question. Where is this problem from? Why is it interesting and important? (3) Please tell in the post, did you try to solve it? What progress did you achieve? Where were you “stuck”?